# Apache Camel: migrate from spring dsl to java dsl

Tags: apache-camel, dsl

I'm thinking about migrating our project from spring dsl to java dsl but I wouldn't like to rewrite the whole config at once. How to use two configs(xml and java) together in camel? Is it reasonable to mix both approach at all?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the change from XML to Java DSL?

Comment: Right now we have two approach spring xml + annotations like @RecipientList. It wasn't good idea. I'm thinking about replacing annotations with xml or move everything(includes spring config) to java config. As for me java config is more flexible, powerful and clear but still I'm not sure if it reasonable to migrate the whole project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's totally reasonable. Reference your RouteBuilder that defines the Java DSL routes first, then any Spring routes like below.

```
<bean id="customerRoute" class="cc.notsoclever.examples.cxf.wsdlfirst.server.CustomerServiceRoutes">
</bean>

<camel:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <routeBuilder ref="customerRoute"/>
    <route id="bar">
        <from uri="direct:bar"/>
        <to uri="mock:bar"/>
    </route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

Comment: yes you can mix routes in xml and java. Camel dont really care which DSL you use to define the routes. At runtime its all the same model.